# Modules and plugin in one package

Tags: extensions, plugin, module

I have built a plugin that is very similar to a google analytics kind of plugin (but for a third party).
Now I have to add a functionality that adds a custom contact form on the sidebar, but I don't know if I can put both on the same physical files or if I should do two different extensions for the two functionalities.

I see that on the  section I can define if a file it's a plugin or a module etc, but I don't know if I can place both on the same xml.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An extension can either be a plugin or a module. It can't be both. That's due to the way modules and plugins are handled.

However you can build the two extensions and package them together and distribute as one zipfile.
See http://docs.joomla.org/Package for some documentation how packages work.

Comment: I have a doubt: Can I put on the same package two different modules? The example you linked talks about one of each type.

Comment: You can have as many as you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for automatic packaging of multiple extensions into all-in-one install package (modules, components, templates, plugins, ... libraries), here is a form to generate such all-in-one package: http://www.joomla-extensions-packager.org/online-packager

And here is an open source PHP library powering the online form: https://github.com/vikijel/joomla-extensions-packager if you want to create some scripts to generate packages yourself